# Linked Rig not updating driver changes

Tags: python, animation, rigging, bones

[image: Master Rig File]

This is the master rig file as you can see. the eye bone's position is changed in a minus direction and as a result, the eye closes.

[image: this is the linked rig where i am doing my animations]

As you can see even after i have reloaded the linked rig, the eye stays the same. so the eye driver is not updating . Have tried everything, Couldnt find the answer. HELP!

Comment: as you can see...nobody commented and nobody answered. This is often the case if the question is unclear or lacks of essential informations. In my opinion it's a good idea to add a blend file so people can check out what you have done and test whether their solution they have in mind will work or won't work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.